# Values of $k$ where $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, b(x)\Leftrightarrow d(x)$ is true.

Tags: logic

I came across this questions I found really confusing

Consider

$b(x):\sqrt{2}x=-2$,

$d(x): 2x-k\geq kx-\sqrt{2}, k\in \mathbb{R}$

Find the values of $k$ where $\forall x \in \mathbb{R},  b(x)\Leftrightarrow d(x)$ is true.

How would you approach this?

Comment: The open formula $b(x)$ tells you what $x$ is. Just replace the value on $d(x)$ in order to make it true.

Comment: $b(x)$ gives $x=-\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I already found values for which both are true, what's confusing to me is when $F\Leftrightarrow F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b(x)$ is true exactly when $x=-\sqrt2$.

And $d(x)$ can be reorganized as $(2-k)x \ge k-\sqrt2 $

If $k=2$, then $d(x)$ is false for all $x$, and therefore does *not* have the same truth value as $b(x)$ for all $x$.

If $k\ne 2$, then we can further simplify $d(x)$ to $x \ge \frac{k-\sqrt2}{2-k}$ or $x \le \frac{k-\sqrt2}{2-k}$ depending on the sign of $2-k$. In either case, however, $d(x)$ is true for infinitely many $x$, which means that $d(x)$ is *not* true for the same $x$ as $b(x)$.

Therefore the answer is: **No values of $k$ make this true.**

Answer (score 0):

Assume $b(x)$.

$b(x) \implies x=-\sqrt{2}$

thus

$2x-k-kx+\sqrt{2}=k(-1+\sqrt{2})-\sqrt{2}\geq 0$

$\iff$

$k\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{-1+\sqrt{2}}$

Proof of $d(x) \implies b(x)$

assume $d(x)$

$(\forall x \in \mathbb R) \; \, 2x-k\geq kx-\sqrt{2}  \implies $

$-2\geq -\sqrt{2}$  if $x=-1$, which is false.

So the statement $d(x)$ is false

and

$d(x) \implies b(x)$ is  always true.

Comment: $d(x)$ is $2x-k\ge kx-\sqrt2$ -- **not** $(\forall x)\;2x-k\ge kx-\sqrt2$. It is in most cases true for _some_ $x$, and $d(x)\Rightarrow b(x)$ is generally false for those $x$.